# Why isn't this loop pausing

Tags: javascript

I have this radio and I'm currently working on getting it to Play, Stop, Play Last, and Play Next. While trying to figure out the Play Last and Play when you get an error on the first load, I ended up running into an issue where it tries to run through my loop again before being called to and fails to load the content as it already has content. After 3-4 tries it stops looping as it should have.

Currently it plays the same song over and over if I click next instead of playing the next song it plays the same thing. Otherwise it does nothing automatically. I believe the issue is with a code; somewhere being wrong.

In the code I tried to set a var code; to route the actions through the program. 
My idea of how the code should work:

```
code = 1; This should loop though songs after song endlessly playing.

code = 0; This should play the last played song unless the current is the first song. Then become code 1.

code = 2; It looked to me like there was an endless loop so I used 2 as a stop point for loops.
```

This is all of the parts that has something to do with the current song.

It's probably easier to understand the code if you read the controls first. It ALWAYS starts with playNext();

Part one gets the link to the file

```
//Part One - Get file directory
function partOne(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '../scripts/radio.php',
        data: {
            attr1: 'value1'
        },
        success: function(returnData) {
            data = returnData;
            lastData = data;
            console.log(data);
            console.log('Step1')
            playFirst();
        }
    });
};
partOne();
```

This part routes the code to the correct location.

```
//Step 2 - Code Highway - Gets new song or sends loop to trash and plays last/current song.
function codeRoute(){
    document.getElementById("playSampleButton").disabled = true;
    setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById("playSampleButton").disabled = false;},5000);
if (code === 1){
    $.ajax({
        url: '../scripts/radio.php',
        data: {
            attr1: 'value1'
        },
        success: function(returnData) {
            data = returnData;
            console.log(data);
            code=2;
            sourceNode.stop(0);
            playFirst();
        }
    });
}if(code === 0);{
    code = 2;
        sourceNode.stop(0);
        console.log(code)
        console.log('0step2')
        playFunct();
    }
    console.log('Step2')
};
```

Probably useless but this part loads and plays the selected file.

```
//Step 3 Loads and plays song
//Load and Play current/next song
function playFirst(){
    document.getElementById("songName").innerHTML = data;
    fileChosen = true;
    setupAudioNodes();
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    console.log('Step3')

    request.addEventListener("progress", updateProgress);
    request.addEventListener("load", transferComplete);
    request.addEventListener("error", transferFailed);
    request.addEventListener("abort", transferCanceled);

    request.open('GET', data, true);
    request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';

    // When loaded decode the data
    request.onload = function() {
        code=1;
        $("#title").html("Infinite");
        $("#album").html("Infinite");
        $("#artist").html("Valence");
        onWindowResize();
        $("#title, #artist, #album").css("visibility", "visible");

        // decode the data
        context.decodeAudioData(request.response, function(buffer) {

        // when the audio is decoded play the sound
        sourceNode.buffer = buffer;
        sourceNode.start(0);
        $("#freq, body").addClass("animateHue");

        //on error
    }, function(e) {
           console.log(e);
       });
    };
    request.send();
};

//Load and Play last/Current when autoplay blocked. 
function playFunct(){
    document.getElementById("songName").innerHTML = lastData;
    fileChosen = true;
    setupAudioNodes();
    console.log('Step3.5')
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.addEventListener("progress", updateProgress);
    request.addEventListener("load", transferComplete);
    request.addEventListener("error", transferFailed);
    request.addEventListener("abort", transferCanceled);

    request.open('GET', lastData, true);
    request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';

    // When loaded decode the lastData
    request.onload = function() {

    $("#title").html("Infinite");
    $("#album").html("Infinite");
    $("#artist").html("Valence");
    onWindowResize();
    $("#title, #artist, #album").css("visibility", "visible");

    // decode the lastData
    context.decodeAudioData(request.response, function(buffer) {

        // when the audio is decoded play the sound
        sourceNode.buffer = buffer;
        sourceNode.start(0);
        console.log(lastData)
        console.log(code)
        console.log('0step3')
        $("#freq, body").addClass("animateHue");
        //on error
    }, function(e) {
        console.log(e);
        });
    };
    request.send();
};

//Step 4
//Auto plays next song. Trashes loop.
var audioBuffer;
var sourceNode;
function setupAudioNodes() {

    // setup a analyser
    analyser = context.createAnalyser();

    // create a buffer source node
    sourceNode = context.createBufferSource();  

    //connect source to analyser as link
    sourceNode.connect(analyser);

    // and connect source to destination
    sourceNode.connect(context.destination);

    //start updating
    rafID = window.requestAnimationFrame(updateVisualization);
    sourceNode.onended = function() {
        console.log('Step4')
        if(code === 1){
            codeRoute();
        }if(code === 2){
            console.log('Trash Deleted')
        }
    }
};
```

Update: The full above code fully working if anyone is interested:

```
//Part One - Get file directory
function partOne(){
    $.ajax({
    url: '../scripts/radio.php',
    data: {
        attr1: 'value1'
    },
    success: function(returnData) {
        data = returnData;
        lastData = data;
        console.log(data);
        console.log('Step1')
        playFirst();
    }
});
};
partOne();

//Step 2 - Code Highway - Gets new song or sends loop to trash and plays last/current song.
function codeRoute(){
    document.getElementById("playSampleButton").disabled = true;
    setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById("playSampleButton").disabled = false;},5000);
if (code === 1){
        $.ajax({
        url: '../scripts/radio.php',
        data: {
        attr1: 'value1'
        },
        success: function(returnData) {
        data = returnData;
        console.log(data);
        code=2;
        sourceNode.stop(0);
        playFirst();
    }
});
        }if(code === 0){
            code = 2;
            sourceNode.stop(0);
            console.log(code)
            console.log('0step2')
            playFunct();
        }
        console.log('Step2')
};

//Step 3 Loads and plays song
//Load and Play current/next song
function playFirst(){
document.getElementById("songName").innerHTML = data;
fileChosen = true;
setupAudioNodes();
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
console.log('Step3')

request.addEventListener("progress", updateProgress);
request.addEventListener("load", transferComplete);
request.addEventListener("error", transferFailed);
request.addEventListener("abort", transferCanceled);

request.open('GET', data, true);
request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';

// When loaded decode the data
request.onload = function() {
    code=1;
$("#title").html("Infinite");
$("#album").html("Infinite");
$("#artist").html("Valence");
onWindowResize();
$("#title, #artist, #album").css("visibility", "visible");

// decode the data
context.decodeAudioData(request.response, function(buffer) {
// when the audio is decoded play the sound
sourceNode.buffer = buffer;
sourceNode.start(0);

$("#freq, body").addClass("animateHue");
//on error
}, function(e) {
console.log(e);
});
};
request.send();
};

//Load and Play last/Current when autoplay blocked. 
function playFunct(){
document.getElementById("songName").innerHTML = lastData;
fileChosen = true;
setupAudioNodes();
console.log('Step3.5')

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

request.addEventListener("progress", updateProgress);
request.addEventListener("load", transferComplete);
request.addEventListener("error", transferFailed);
request.addEventListener("abort", transferCanceled);

request.open('GET', lastData, true);
request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';

// When loaded decode the lastData
request.onload = function() {
        code=1;
$("#title").html("Infinite");
$("#album").html("Infinite");
$("#artist").html("Valence");
onWindowResize();
$("#title, #artist, #album").css("visibility", "visible");

// decode the lastData
context.decodeAudioData(request.response, function(buffer) {
// when the audio is decoded play the sound
sourceNode.buffer = buffer;
sourceNode.start(0);
console.log(lastData)
console.log(code)
console.log('0step3')
$("#freq, body").addClass("animateHue");
//on error
}, function(e) {
console.log(e);
});
};
request.send();

};

//Controls
//Play A Song Again
function playAgain(){
        console.log(data);
        code = 0;
        codeRoute();
}
//Stop Playing
function stopPlaying(){
    code = 2;
    sourceNode.stop(0);
}
//Play Next Song
//Step 1
function playNext(){

        if(context.state == 'suspended'){
            code =0;
            playFunct();

}else{
    code =1;//0; to play last song.
    console.log(code)
    codeRoute();
}
}

//Step 4
//Auto plays next song. Trashes loop.
var audioBuffer;
var sourceNode;
function setupAudioNodes() {
    // setup a analyser
    analyser = context.createAnalyser();
    // create a buffer source node
    sourceNode = context.createBufferSource();  
    //connect source to analyser as link
    sourceNode.connect(analyser);
    // and connect source to destination
    sourceNode.connect(context.destination);
    //start updating
    rafID = window.requestAnimationFrame(updateVisualization);
    sourceNode.onended = function() {
        console.log('Step4')
        if(code === 2){
        console.log('Trash Deleted')
        }else{
        if(code === 1){
        codeRoute();
        }
        }

}
};
```

Comment: `if(code = 1)` should be `if(code === 1)` for starters...

Comment: Is there any way to reduce this code down to an easier to read sample?

Comment: I didn't realize it was so big. I broke it up into sections still in order and explained each part. The bulk I don't think is where the issue lies so I specified that one. Hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the section labeled "This part routes to the current location" the snippet:

```
if(code === 0);{
    code = 2;
    sourceNode.stop(0);
    console.log(code)
    console.log('0step2')
    playFunct();
}
```

The if statement should not have a semi-colon (i.e.)

```
if(code === 0){
    code = 2;
    sourceNode.stop(0);
    console.log(code)
    console.log('0step2')
    playFunct();
}
```

Comment: Ok if any other problems, comment to this answer and (no guarantees that I can help) ill try to help. Also, mark this as the answer then please :) -Happy Coding, G